# PostgreSql конвертация даты

Tags: postgresql

Как привести такую дату в текстовом формате "Sep 25 2017 08:00:00:000PM" в timestamp.

> Использую to_timestamp(StartTime,,'DD MM YYYY')
>
> > ERROR:  invalid value "Se" for "DD" DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.
>
> ********** Ошибка **********

Я думал он его обрежет, а нет.

Comment: А вы не пробовали посмотреть документацию https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html там же все написано ... У вас идет название месяца, число и т.д. так и пишите маску именно в этом порядке `Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM`

Comment: ERROR:  error executing query: OCIStmtExecute failed to execute remote query
DETAIL:  ORA-01856: BC/B.C. or AD/A.D. required Я посмотрел, этот баг исправили в сл. версиях Oracle_fdw если у меня Postgres 9.3 Смогу-ли я обновиться на версия 2.*? или так же на 1.1 останусь

Comment: Просто как запрос всё работает, но почему то при запросе update в oracle_fdw выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Я не понял, вопрос по `Oracle` или по `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: Oracle_fdw Расширение для Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

А вы не пробовали посмотреть документацию postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html там же все написано ... У вас идет название месяца, число и т.д. так и пишите маску именно в этом порядке Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS:MSAM – Mike